# chaining promises to force async

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm using promises to fetch large albums of images and when pull random samples from that album. I have managed to request all the albums and then push the links to images to an array of objects.

Now I want to print out that array but only after I've actually filled it. Whenever I add a `.then()` on the end it prints out only the initialized empty array.

What can I do to force async and only print the array once it's filled. (I'm printing it out at the bottom)

```js
let findImagesCatalyst = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //url options 
    const options = {
      url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/time/',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Client-ID xxxx"
      }
    };

    //inital request
    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
      //parse the response
      body = JSON.parse(body)
        //access the data in the response
      const responseData = body.data;
      //filter only those with image counts great than 50
      const largeAlbums = responseData.filter(findDumps)
        //test to see if a dump is present
      if (largeAlbums.length > 0) {
        largeAlbums.forEach(function(i) {})
        resolve(largeAlbums)
      } else {
        reject()
      }

    })

  })
  //if successful in finding a dump, then go through them and find their albumIds
  .then(function(largeAlbums) {
    let dumpIds = largeAlbums.map(index => index.id)
    return dumpIds;
  })
  //with the album/dump ids, get each of them with a new request
  .then(function(dumpIds) {
    //for each of the dumpIds create the needed url using ES6  and then request it. 
    dumpIds.forEach(function(i) {
      const albumUrlOptions = {
          url: `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/${i}/images`,
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Client-ID xxxx"
          }
        }
        //make a request to each of the albums/dumps
      request(albumUrlOptions, function(err, res, body) {
        body = JSON.parse(body)
        const responseData = body.data
          //pick one sample image from the album/dump
        let sampleImage = responseData[randomSelector(responseData.length)].link;
        dumps.push({
          "dump": i,
          'sample': sampleImage
        })

      })
    })

    return dumps;
  })

.then(function(dumps) {
  console.log(dumps)
})
```

Comment: if you need to wait for multiple Promises to resolve, you want to use `Promise.all` on an array of promises

Comment: @JaromandaX would that mean I need to take everything that's in a .then() and break them out into their own named functions?

Comment: You stuck another async operation (your second request()) right in the middle of your code and did not treat it as async like you did everything else.  You should use a promise for that too and you can chain that right into the sequence.

Comment: Right now, the last `then` callback is fired once `dumpIds` is iterated through, not when the requests complete. Alternatively, you can return a promise for the second last `then` callback, which is only resolved (with dumps passed as the argument) once all requests are completed (similar to how you implemented the albums array). See the section on return values in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then.

Comment: @MaxSindwani Thanks, could you explain the return a promise concept?
The request URL is set dynamic for each index so if I take the request function out of that section won't it only have the last url?

Comment: @Somethingismissing The answers below are great examples. The documentation basically states that you can also return a promise for chaining requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're second .then should return Promise.all of the (promisified) requests

```
.then(function(dumpIds) {
    //for each of the dumpIds create the needed url using ES6  and then request it. 
    return Promise.all(dumpIds.map(function(i) {
        const albumUrlOptions = {
            url: `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/${i}/images`,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Client-ID xxxx"
            }
        };
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            //make a request to each of the albums/dumps
            request(albumUrlOptions, function(err, res, body) {
                body = JSON.parse(body)
                const responseData = body.data
                    //pick one sample image from the album/dump
                let sampleImage = responseData[randomSelector(responseData.length)].link;
                resolve({
                    "dump": i,
                    'sample': sampleImage
                });
            });
        });
    }))
})
```

As you are using node.js, which has very good ES2015+ implementation, you can simplify (in my opinion) your code by, firstly, creating a "promisified version of `request`

```
let requestP = (options) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        resolve({res, body});
    });
});
```

The rest of the code could be then re-written as follows

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/time/',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Client-ID xxxx"
  }
};

//inital request
let findImagesCatalyst = requestP(options)
.then(({res, body}) => {
    //parse the response
    body = JSON.parse(body)
        //access the data in the response
    const responseData = body.data;
    //filter only those with image counts great than 50
    const largeAlbums = responseData.filter(findDumps)
        //test to see if a dump is present
    if (largeAlbums.length > 0) {
        largeAlbums.forEach(function(i) {})
        return(largeAlbums)
    } else {
        return Promise.reject();
    }
})
//if successful in finding a dump, then go through them and find their albumIds
.then((largeAlbums) => largeAlbums.map(index => index.id))
//with the album/dump ids, get each of them with a new request
.then((dumpIds) => 
    //for each of the dumpIds create the needed url using ES6  and then request it. 
    Promise.all(dumpIds.map((i) => {
        const albumUrlOptions = {
            url: `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/${i}/images`,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Client-ID xxxx"
            }
        };
        return requestP(albumUrlOptions)
        .then(({res, body}) => {
            body = JSON.parse(body)
            const responseData = body.data
                //pick one sample image from the album/dump
            let sampleImage = responseData[randomSelector(responseData.length)].link;
            return({
                "dump": i,
                'sample': sampleImage
            });
        });
    }))
)
.then(function(dumps) {
    console.log(dumps)
});
```

Comment: I think you need to return `Promise.all` for the last callback to fire after all of the promises have been resolved.

Comment: `() => Promise.all(...)` === `() => { return Promise.all(...); }` - so, yes, it **is** returning `Promise.all`

Comment: Ah, my bad! Didn't notice the arrow function

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a few building blocks here:

1. Request for imgur albums reflected into `options` object.
2. `findDumps` — a simple function that you filter the list of albums against.
3. A function that applies the preceding two and returns an *array of large albums*. It's an asynchronous function, so it likely employs Promise.
4. A function that takes every item of the *array of large albums* and receives a *single image*. It's an asynchronous function, so, again, a Promise.
5. You want to wait until all the *single images* have been received.
6. Finally, you expect an array of objects of two properties: "dump" and "sample".

Let's try to contruct an example.

```
const findImagesCatalyst = new Promise((resolveImagesCatalyst, rejectImagesCatalyst) => {
  const options = {
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/time/',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Client-ID xxxx'
    }
  };

  request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    //access the data in the response
    const responseData = JSON.parse(body).data;
    //filter only those with image counts great than 50
    const largeAlbums = responseData.filter(findDumps);

    //test to see if a dump is present
    if (largeAlbums.length > 0) {
      // /!\ The trickiest part here: we won't resolve this promise until an "inner Promise" has been resolved.
      // Note that next line declares a new function to resolve inner Promise, resolveLargeAlbum. Now we have two functions:
      // - resolveImagesCatalyst - to resolve the main Promise, and
      // - resolveLargeAlbum — to resolve every image request, and there can be many of them.
      const imagesPromises = largeAlbums.map(largeAlbum => new Promise((resolveLargeAlbum, rejectLargeAlbun) => {
        // take id from every large album
        const dumpId = largeAlbum.id;
        // declare options for inner request
        const options = {
          url: `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/${i}/images`,
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "Client-ID xxxx"
          }
        };

        request(albumUrlOptions, (err, res, body) => {
          const responseData = JSON.parse(body).data;
            //pick one sample image from the album/dump
          const sampleImage = responseData[randomSelector(responseData.length)].link;

          if (sampleImage) {
            // A-HA!
            // It's inner Promise's resolve function. For N albums, there will be N resolveLargeAlbum calls. Just a few lines below, we're waiting for all of them to get resolved.
            resolveLargeAlbum({
              dump: dumpId,
              sample: sampleImage
            });
          } else {
            rejectLargeAlbun('Sorry, could not receive sample image:', dumpId, responseData);
          }
        });
      }));

      // Now we have imagePromises, an array of Promises. When you have an array of Promises, you can use Promise.all to wait until all of them are resolved:
      Promise.all(imagesPromises).then(responses => {
        // Take a look at responses: it has to be an array of objects of two properties: dump and sample.
        // Also, note that we finally use outer Promise's resolve function, resolveImagesCatalyst.
        resolveImagesCatalyst(responses);
      }).catch(errors => {
        rejectImagesCatalyst(errors);
      });
    } else {
      rejectImagesCatalyst('Sorry, nope.');
    }
  });
});
```

That's a huge one. What you really need to see is that

- With [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you can wait for a collection of Promises to get resolved, and the "then" part won't get executed until *all* of them have been resolved.
- You can [put a Promise into a Promise](http://blacksportsonline.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Michigan-Hype-Video-Xzibit.png), and resolve outer Promise when inner Promise gets resolved.
- The code is really hard to read, because the order of execution is not top-to-bottom. If you use Webpack with Babel, you might want to take a look at [async/await](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/). With async/await, the code *looks* synchronous: you read it from top to bottom and that's exactly the order results of its execution appear, but under the hood, it's all asynchronous. Pretty neat ES6 feature, imho.

Comment: This code removes most of the promise chaining in the original question, for no real reason

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure there is no existing Node module that is handles your imgur searching business.  Search on npms.io.
2. If there is no existing module, find one that is close and expand it for your use case (hot images).
3. If you really can't find a module for imgur to expand, then make your own.  All of the imgur request stuff goes in its own module (and own file).
4. Make sure that module supports promises.
5. Your code should look something like this:

```or-tag-here
import {getHotAlbums, getAlbumImages, config} from 'imgur';

config({clientID: 'BLAHXXXX'});

async function getHotImages() {
   let hotAlbums = await getHotAlbums();
   hotAlbums = hotAlbums.filter(a => a.imageCount > 50);

   const sampleImages = []; 
   let albumIDs = hotAlbums.map(a => a.id);

   for (let albumID of albumIDs) {
     const images = await getAlbumImages(albumID);
     const randomImageNum = Math.round(Math.random()*images.length)+1;
     sampleImages.push(images[randomImageNum].link);
   }
   return sampleImages;
}
```

Comment: interesting answer, all the code that actually does anything is in a module called `imgur` that doesn't actually exist!

Comment: In fact, it does exist: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgur. Still, it doesn't export a function `getHotAlbums` and such.

Comment: I can see you guys put a lot of effort into your answers and I'm sure he will appreciate having code that is complete.  I just think that with so many imgur modules on npm one of them probably has most if not all of what he wants, and anyway it would make more sense to build on one of them.  If he really wants then he can just put existing code in another module.  But the key to cleaning this up to is separation of concerns and taking advantage of `async/await`.